# php pdo insert statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo

I have a site on host gator. I can connect with my pdo statement but the statement for the insert doesnt seem to work. Right now I have defined the values but i plan to use variabled pulled from a $_POST from a form on the previous page.

```
<?php

/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'pressgym_admin';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = '*******';  <-started out on purpose

try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=pressgym_press", $username, $password);
/*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
$qry = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO contact (Name, Email Address, Message, Date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?');
$qry->execute(array('Brandon', 'Brandon.braner@gmail.com', 'test message', '3.12.12'));

echo 'entry succesfull';

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>

   describe contact;
   Name varchar(255)    NO  PRI     
   EmailAddress varchar(255)    NO          
   Message  longtext    NO          
   Date varchar(255)    YES
```

Comment: Enable PDO Exceptions with `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: I would change the host name to something fake.  If that's a real IP, you're just asking for abuse....

Comment: The only proper answer for some reason added as a comment.

Comment: @MikeB 's comment fixed the issue I had.  Disabling exceptions by default seems like an awful design decision.  It creates a scenario where PDO is the cryptic wife ("No, it's _fine_.") and PHP is the oblivious husband ("Fine? Well all right! Onto the next thing...").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL syntax in your `prepare` command contains errors:

```
qry = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO contact (Name, Email Address, Message, Date) VALUES (?, ?, ?), ?');
```

should be

```
qry = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO contact (Name, `Email Address`, Message, Date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
```

Comment: wow you were quick ;)  i saw that after i posted it, still doesnt work

Comment: @BrandonBraner: I've updated my answer to reflect that the identifier for the `Email Address` column needs to be quoted in order to handle the space it contains.

Comment: aaw my bad. i didn't notice the space, and assumed it to be another column

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar: Credit where it's due, I only noticed it after reading your answer!  +1

Comment: +1 for the answer. and @Brandon Braner, try not to use space ( ) in column names.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar: On your comment (doesn't really make sense to +1 the wrong answer...)

Comment: @eggyal  I got an error in my php when i did that, so i removed the space from the table and the code and still nothing

Comment: @Brandon Braner please provide with some error code. by adding the attribute `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` just after you open the connection. as mentioned by @Mike B

Comment: @BrandonBraner: can you revise your question to add the table schema (output of `DESCRIBE contact;`)?

Comment: A lot of guessing and syntax-checking by eyesight.. just turn on exceptions and let MySQL tell you what's wrong :)

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: @BrandonBraner: I think you may still be missing the closing parenthesis of the `VALUES` clause.

Comment: holy bejibus batman i am dumb... i deleted the ) in the wrong spot but did not at ) in the correct spot...all is functioning now...now to test with the variables ;)

Answer (score 2):

you have a syntax error. the following line

```
$qry = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO contact (Name, Email Address, Message, Date) VALUES(?, ?, ?), ?');
```

should be

```
$qry = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO contact (Name, Email Address, Message, Date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
```

Update:

your column name Email Address contains a space escape it by using proper quote identifier like

```
INSERT INTO contact (Name, `Email Address`, Message, Date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'
```